# Action client waiting forever for server to start

Tags: ros

I'm in the process of writing an action cpp file and the client side seems to be stuck waiting for the server to start and I'm not quite sure why.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <actionlib/server/simple_action_server.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>

#include <mavros_msgs/SetMode.h>
#include <mavros_msgs/CommandBool.h>

#include <rovexp/ModeAction.h>

typedef actionlib::SimpleActionServer<rovexp::ModeAction> Server;

class ModeActionServer {

protected:
ros::NodeHandle nh_;

ros::ServiceClient arming_client_;
ros::ServiceClient set_mode_client_;

Server mode_server_;

rovexp::ModeFeedback feedback_;
rovexp::ModeResult result_;
std::string action_name_;
public:
ModeActionServer(std::string name) :
    mode_server_(nh_, name, boost::bind(&ModeActionServer::executeCB, this, _1), false),
    action_name_(name)
{
    mode_server_.start();
    ROS_INFO("Mode action server started...");
}
~ModeActionServer(void) { }

void executeCB(const rovexp::ModeGoalConstPtr &goal)
{
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("mode experiment started...");

    /*
    set_mode_client_ = nh_.serviceClient<mavros_msgs::SetMode>("mavros/set_mode");
    mavros_msgs::SetMode offb_set_mode;
    offb_set_mode.request.custom_mode = goal->mode_num;

    set_mode_client_.call(offb_set_mode);
    */

    arming_client_ = nh_.serviceClient<mavros_msgs::CommandBool>("mavros/cmd/arming");
    ros::Rate rate(20.0);
    mavros_msgs::CommandBool arm_cmd;
    arm_cmd.request.value = true;
    arming_client_.call(arm_cmd);
}
};

typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<rovexp::ModeAction> Client;

void modeActionClient(uint8_t mode_num)

{
Client client("mode_client", true);

ROS_INFO("Waiting for action server to start");
client.waitForServer();

rovexp::ModeGoal goal;
goal.mode_num = mode_num;
printf("%d\t4\n",goal.mode_num);
client.sendGoal(goal);

client.waitForResult();
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
if(std::string(argv[1])=="-server")
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "mode_server");
  ModeActionServer server("mode_server");
  //server.start();
  ros::spin();

}
else if(std::string(argv[1])=="-client")
{
    if ( std::string(argv[2])=="-h" ) {
        printf("Use: rosrun rovexp mode -client @mode\n"); 
        exit(-1);
    }
    ros::init(argc, argv, "mode_action_client");
    uint8_t mode_num = atoi(argv[2]);
    modeActionClient(mode_num);
}
printf("done\n");   
return 0;
}
```

The terminal will output "Mode action server started..." and "Waiting for action server to start" but never gets to "mode experiment started...".

So it would seem that the client gets stuck on

```
client.waitForServer();
```

A lot of what I've done was inspired by a ROS tutorial ([link](https://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/RunningServerAndClient)) and there's works fine on my pc. Having a hard time seeing the difference.

I'm running ubuntu 16.04LTS and ROS kinetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same topics for the master and the client.

```
Client client("mode_client", true);
```

starts a client that looks for a server that listens on the `~mode_client/goal` topic, but you started the server on `~mode_server/goal`. 
Could you run both nodes and add the output of

```
rostopic list
```

to your question?